# Linting errors with KingFisher 5.12.0 - Swift 5.1.2

Tags: ios, kingfisher

I'm getting the following errors when running swiftlint on the Kingfisher library in my project. I'm running Swift 5.1.2
XCode 11.2.1

```
Testing failed:
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Cannot convert value of type '() -> ImageDownloader' to expected argument type '((_, SessionDelegate.SessionChallengeFunc) -> Void)?' (aka 'Optional<(_, (URLSession, URLAuthenticationChallenge, (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, Optional<URLCredential>) -> ())) -> ()>')
    Cannot convert value of type '() -> ImageDownloader' to expected argument type '((_, SessionDelegate.SessionTaskChallengeFunc) -> Void)?' (aka 'Optional<(_, (URLSession, URLSessionTask, URLAuthenticationChallenge, (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, Optional<URLCredential>) -> ())) -> ()>')
    Cannot convert value of type '() -> ImageDownloader' to expected argument type '((_, Int) -> Bool)?'
    Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((_, (URL, Result<URLResponse, KingfisherError>)) -> Void)?'
    Use of unresolved identifier 'task'
    Use of unresolved identifier 'task'
    Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
    Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((_, (Result<(Data, URLResponse?), KingfisherError>, [SessionDataTask.TaskCallback])) -> Void)?'
    Expected ',' separator
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Expected expression
    Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((_, (SessionDataTask.CancelToken, SessionDataTask.TaskCallback)) -> Void)?' (aka 'Optional<(_, (Int, SessionDataTask.TaskCallback)) -> ()>')
    Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
    Insufficient indentation of next 2 lines in multi-line string literal
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Testing cancelled because the build failed.
```

I've tried the follwoing: 
swift run swiftformat .
swiftlint autocorrect

But no dice, I have it installed as a cocoapod. And i'm asking here before I open an issue with the Kingfisher project itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue when the script for swiftFormat autocorrected Kingfisher pod. You need to remove pod manually (or through `pod deintegrate`), re-install it (to reverse changes) and then, if like me, you call swiftlint as a script in build phase, change it to

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftFormat/CommandLineTool/swiftformat" . --exclude Pods,Generated
```